# knockout foreach in the middle of a table

Tags: knockout.js, html-table

I have a table like so:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
  <tr>
   <td>static 1a</td><td>static 2a</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>dynamic 1b</td><td>dynamic 2b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>dynamic 1c</td><td>dynamic 2c</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

The dynamic fields need to be a knockout foreach to iterate all the properties of the object.  The only thing I can think to do is something like:

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreachprop: properties">
        <tr><td><span data-bind="text: propertyName"></span></td><td><span data-bind="text: value"></span></td></tr>
    </tbody>
```

Which technically works, but it screws with my styling because the static row should be part of the tbody.  What else can I bind to the for each?  I must be missing a simple solution.

**update**: I'm actually not using "foreach", I'm using a custom function that iterates through the properties.  When I try to use <!-- ko foreachprop:> properties -- I get the following console error:

> Uncaught Error: The binding 'foreachprop' cannot be used with virtual
>   elements

Here is the foreachprop function

```
ko.bindingHandlers.foreachprop = {
    transformObject: function (obj) {
        var properties = [];
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var newObj = obj[key];
                newObj.propertyName = key;
                properties.push(newObj);
            }
        }
        return properties;
    },
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            properties = ko.bindingHandlers.foreachprop.transformObject(value);
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { foreach: properties });
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `foreach` without a container element (documentation: [note 4](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)) To handle this, you can use the *containerless control flow syntax*. You just need a specfial comment line where you can put your `foreach`:

```
<tbody data-bind="">
   <tr>
     <td>static 1a</td><td>static 2a</td>
   </tr>
   <!-- ko foreach: properties -->
      <tr>
         <td>
             <span data-bind="text: propertyName"></span>
         </td>
         <td>
             <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
         </td>
     </tr>
   <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

If you are using a custom binding `foreachprop` then you need to configure it work with virtual elements. You can do with after the bindingHandlers declaration with:

```
ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.foreachprop = true;
```

You should note that you may need to rewrite your DOM manipulation logic inside your custom binding to support the virtual elements. You can find an extensive documentation on the `virtualElements` helpers in the documentation: [Creating custom bindings that support virtual elements](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html)

Comment: Steve Sanderson is a genius.

Comment: Any side effects of doing it like this?  Performance changes, etc?

Comment: Bad news, updating my question.  Sorry.

Comment: @ScottBeeson please check the documentation how to [create custom bindings that support virtual elements](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also realized you can have multiple tbody elements in a table.  This solution fixes my problem so I thought I'd share it, but I like nemesv's better.

Comment: it is possible but you have to remember that each tbody has its own line counter. It useful when you apply styling every other line (see http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html)